# MinGW compile c

Tags: c++, c, compilation, mingw

I installed MinGW, and i wrote the following code test

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
#if defined(__WIN32__)
    printf("hello win.");
#else
    printf("hello unix.");
#endif
    return 0;
}
```

then  compiled and run.

```
V002294@DESKTOP-A0H4TOJ /c/Users/V002294
$ gcc test.c -o test

V002294@DESKTOP-A0H4TOJ /c/Users/V002294
$ ./test.exe
hello win.
```

why not `"hello unix"`?

Comment: Because your target platform is win32.

Comment: I ran in Ubuntu 18.04, I got `hello unix`.

Comment: If I want the Windows platform to compile and run and print “hello unix", I should probably use Cygwin?

Comment: Run `which gcc` to find out what compiler you are using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`__WIN32__` must be defined given the result your getting.

It looks like when you run `gcc` it's using MinGW's gcc.

Check your `PATH` environment variable (`echo $PATH`) to see if the MinGW location is in it before the Linux version. Or just run `which gcc` to see which one is being used.

Or maybe you don't have any other gcc installed and it that's why its using MinGW gcc by default.